# Why do 2 EPSG Codes exist for the same coordinate system?

Tags: epsg

I sometimes need to publish data in Gauss-Kruger zone 3 and was wondering why there are now the following EPSG Codes which define this CRS.

1. 31467 - DHDN / 3-degree Gauss-Kruger zone 3
2. 31463 - DHDN / 3-degree Gauss zone 3

The Parameters are identical. Then why 2 Codes?

Comment: I cant find EPSG 31463 anywhere. https://epsg.io/?q=31463 or epsg-registry.org

Comment: @Spacedman see https://epsg.io/31463

Answer (score 8):

EPSG:**31463** seems to be deprecated and EPSG:**31467** is the correct one.

http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/dhdn-3-degree-gauss-zone-3/ is stating:

> ProjCRS related to inappropriate coordinate system resulting in incorrect axes and name. Use EPSG:31467 instead.

you can see see this, if you compare the AXIS definitions:

```
PROJCS["DHDN / 3-degree Gauss zone 3 (deprecated)",
GEOGCS["DHDN",
    DATUM["Deutsches_Hauptdreiecksnetz",
        SPHEROID["Bessel 1841",6377397.155,299.1528128,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7004"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6314"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4314"]],
UNIT["metre",1,
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",9],
PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
PARAMETER["false_easting",3500000],
PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","31463"],
AXIS["X",EAST],
AXIS["Y",NORTH]]
```

with:

```
PROJCS["DHDN / Gauss-Kruger zone 3",
GEOGCS["DHDN",
    DATUM["Deutsches_Hauptdreiecksnetz",
        SPHEROID["Bessel 1841",6377397.155,299.1528128,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7004"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6314"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4314"]],
UNIT["metre",1,
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",9],
PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
PARAMETER["false_easting",3500000],
PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","31467"],
AXIS["Y",EAST],
AXIS["X",NORTH]]
```

Comment: I need to add spatialreference.org to my list of places to look for EPSG codes. Thanks. Although epsg.io hides it under the "deprecated" link.

Comment: EPSG-registry is still the authority and it reports one more version of axis order and labels http://epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::31467 `AXIS["northing (X)",north,ORDER[1]],
    AXIS["easting (Y)",east,ORDER[2]],`

Comment: Note on EPSG registry: To look at "deprecated" objects, you have set up a login. It's only used send you notices of new versions.